# Login Redirect Issue after 3.7 upgrade

Tags: joomla-3.7

After upgrading to 3.7 i got an issues with one of my site.
This site is user only, when trying to access it it should (was until 3.6.x) redirect you to a login page, after the 3.7 upgrade it gives a **The page isn't redirecting properly error**.

To recreate the issue just set a new 3.7 joomla installation home menu item to Access = Registered

- http://localhost/testjoomla
- will redirect to: http://localhost/testjoomla/index.php/component/users/?view=login&Itemid=101 (ERROR)
- Removing the: **&Itemid=101** (WORKS)

Tested with php 5.5.30 & 7.1.1

Comment: I suggest you report this on the [Joomla Github Issue Tracker](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a Login Menu Item solves this bug.
System Page Cache must be turned off, another bug of 3.7

Answer (score 0):

See answer on github: Blank pages in Joomla 3.7 when System - Page Cache is activated #15691 https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/15691

Comment: Tested System - Page Cache but has no effect on this issue.